# get Keycloak rpt in javascript

Tags: javascript, vue.js, keycloak, rpt

I have tried so far to get the rpt token using the authz.js provided on the keycloak server. But I get an empty rpt back

```
const authorization = new KeycloakAuthorization(rootState.keycloak.keycloak);
      this._vm.$log.debug(
        "The auth object: ", authorization
      );

      authorization.entitlement('extranet').then(function (rpt) {
        console.log(
          "The rpt object entitlement: ", rpt
        );
    });
```

Has anyone ever gotten the rpt into vue/JS successfully and have an example?

Comment: `await new` ... hmmm ... does keycloak constructor return a promise or a thenable?

Comment: Never heard of keycloak until 4 minutes ago. Have you read any [documentation](https://www.keycloak.org/securing-apps/vue)

Comment: yes i use keycloak since 2 years and works a lot with the documentation and followed https://wjw465150.gitbooks.io/keycloak-documentation/content/authorization_services/topics/enforcer/js-adapter.html

Comment: Well. Your code looks nothing like code that would actually work if you look at the link

Comment: Even in your link `var authorization = new KeycloakAuthorization...` no await there either.  Seems you are *doing it wrong*

Comment: okay i edited now my code and put all the code

Comment: So you've completley rewritten it? And it still doesn't look anything like the code in your link or mine

Comment: okay and how is my code different from the doc?

Comment: You edited again? Looks different.  Is extranet the client id of the resource server?

Comment: I see it uses .then with 3 callbacks ... ongrant ondeny and onerror ... so, not a promise. but i guess ingrant is called?

Comment: my keycloak client id

Comment: Not the question i asked, but not at all inconsistent